# How to execute oracle function in oracle apex online

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have function in oracle apex that returns true or false. When i use sqlcommand function of oracle apex I'm not able to execute the function

```
function authenticateUser(p_username in varchar2 ,p_password in varchar2 )
        return boolean 
        is 
         p_user Users.USERNAME%type;
        begin
             select USERNAME into p_user from Users  where   upper(USERNAME)=upper(p_username) and  upper(PASSWORD) = upper(p_password);
                 return true;
             exception
                when NO_DATA_FOUND then 
                return false;
        end authenticateUser;
```

When i run

```
begin

PKG_AUTHORIZATION.authenticateUser(:p_username,:p_password);
end;
```

It display error as

```
ORA-06550: line 3, column 1:
PLS-00221: 'AUTHENTICATEUSER' is not a procedure or is undefined
ORA-06550: line 3, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721
1. begin
2. PKG_AUTHORIZATION.authenticateUser(:p_username,:p_password);
3. end;
```

and When I write

```
select PKG_AUTHORIZATION.authenticateUser(:p_username,:p_password) from dual;
```

It throws error as

```
ORA-00902: invalid datatype
```

Comment: You cant select the result from the function because it returns a boolean which is not a datatype that SQL knows about. Is you function defined in the package spec ? Do you need to qualify the name with the schema ? Do you have permissions to run the  function ? We can't see how the function is defined in the package or who you are running it as so an answer is tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that function exists within the package, right?

As it returns Boolean, you can't use it directly from SQL, but PL/SQL, such as:

```
declare
  l_val varchar2(20);
begin
  l_val := case when PKG_AUTHORIZATION.authenticateUser(:p_username,:p_password) then 'true'
                else 'false'
           end;
end;
```

But, you don't have to worry about it. As you tagged the question with the Oracle Apex tag, I presume you use this function for your own authentication (instead of built-in one). If that's so, you just have to **name** the function which is supposed to do the job and put its name into the "Authentication function name" item.